# Problemas con filas y columnas en Vue/Nuxt Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt

Estoy tratando de hacer un blog y cuando entro en la página donde deberían mostrarse todas las entradas solo se ve la primera columna con contenido y todas las entradas una debajo de otra; la segunda columna si existe,sale el borde negro, pero la muestra vacía.
También es extraño, pues al poner el md=4, me deberían salir tres columnas, solo me salen dos y la segunda sin contenido. Alguna ayuda, por favor.

```
<template>
  <div class="container-blog">
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h1>Terapias</h1>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col
        md="4"
        v-for="(element, indexServeis) in serveis"
        :key="indexServeis"
        class="col-blog"
      >
        <div v-if="element.id == 'terapias'">
          <div v-for="(producte, i) in element.projectes" :key="i">
            <nuxt-link :to="'/terapias/' + producte.id">
              <h2>{{ producte.titol }}</h2>
            </nuxt-link>
            <div v-for="(img, indeximg) in producte.imagen" :key="indeximg">
              <v-img :src="img" class="img-blog"> </v-img>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 30px; font-weight: 900">
              {{ producte.text }}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import portfoli from "@/dades/portfoli";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.portfoliVue = portfoli;
    this.serveis = this.portfoliVue.index.llista;
  },
  data() {
    return {
      serveis: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.container-blog {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.col-blog{
  border: 1px solid black;

}
```

Creo que con esto ya esta, pero si necesitan algun archivo más, díganmelo. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He conseguido resolverlo, el problemas estaba en la condicional de "terapias". Hay dos valores en element.id, son "terapias" y "cursos". Como creo las columnas antes del condicional, me crea todas las columnas, a la derecha las de terapias y a la izquierda la de cursos, pero la de cursos no la pinta, por eso se me quedaban columnas sin contenido. Lo resolvi haciendo un forEach antes y pasandole solo el array de projectes de las terapias.

```
 <template>
  <v-container fluid>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <h1>Terapias</h1>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="fila-blog">
      <v-col
        md="6"
        v-for="(element, indexServeis) in terapiasBlog"
        :key="indexServeis"
        class="col-blog"
      >
            <nuxt-link :to="'/terapias/' + element.id">
              <h2>{{ element.titol }}</h2>
            </nuxt-link>
            <div v-for="(img, indeximg) in element.imagen" :key="indeximg">
              <v-img :src="img" class="img-blog"> </v-img>
            </div>
            <div style="padding: 30px; font-weight: 900">
              {{ element.text }}
            </div>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import portfoli from "@/dades/portfoli";

export default {
  mounted() {
    this.portfoliVue = portfoli;
    this.serveis = this.portfoliVue.index.llista;
    this.serveis.forEach((serveiBlog) => {
        if (serveiBlog.id === 'terapias') {
          this.terapiasBlog = serveiBlog.projectes;
          console.log(this.terapiasBlog);
        }
      });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      serveis: false,
      terapiasBlog: false,
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.col-blog{
  border: 1px solid black;

}
</style>
```